# How would I go about scrolling a name across a LoL shield with a potentiometer?

Tags: led, shields, potentiometer

I am fairly new to Arduino programming and I have been set with the task of scrolling my name across a [LoL shield](http://jimmieprodgers.com/kits/lolshield/) with a potentiometer. I really don't have any idea how to do this and when I tried to look it up online there is nothing for such a task. I did look at the library references on the LoL shield website but I couldn't make sense of it.

What I did find was a [LoL shield sequencer](http://sequoia.github.io/LSS/) to allow animation on the LoL shield and I figured that might help but I don't know how to use that code to create a scrolling effect with a potentiometer.

Comment: What does "with a potentiometer" mean?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I think it means that the text is "linked" to the string (i.e. 0% = first part of string, 50% = middle of string, etc.)

Comment: i mean the position of the text is controlled by the current position of the potentiometer. so as the potentiometer is rotated the text scrolls across the screen. if the potentiometer stops then so does the text.

Answer (score 4):

You know how wide the display is. You know how wide the text is. You know the position of the potentiometer. With those you can determine where in the text (if the text is wider) or display (if the display is wider) you need to start drawing from and where you need to stop drawing. Subtracting the text width from the display width will give you the range for performing linear interpolation with the pot position.

Answer (score 2):

The [LoL shield library](https://github.com/jprodgers/LoLshield) now supports exactly<sup>1</sup> what you want.

If you choose the `LoLShield_FontTest` example it will scroll "HELLO WORLD!" across your shield. Change your text as required.

```C++
static const char test[]="HELLO WORLD!   ";
```

Example of the word "WORLD":

[image: Hello World]

And in higher contrast to make it more obvious:

[image: Hello World high contrast]

---

(1) Except for the potentiometer. In the example code where it automatically scrolls:

```C++
  for (int8_t x=DISPLAY_COLS, i=0; ; x--) {
    LedSign::Clear();
    for (int8_t x2=x, i2=i; x2<DISPLAY_COLS;) {
       int8_t w = Font::Draw (test[i2], x2, 0);
       x2 += w, i2 = (i2+1) % strlen(test);
       if (x2 <= 0)  // off the display completely?
         x = x2, i = i2;
       }
       delay(500);
    }
```

You would amend it to do an analogRead to set the position of `x`.

---

### Example of using a potentiometer

Based on the Charliplexing example, the code below uses a pot connected to A0 to control the scroll position:

```C++
#include "Charliplexing.h"
#include "Myfont.h"

char * test = "full ASCII charset: $ % & ! [ ] { }";
int len; // length of this string

void setup()                    // run once, when the sketch starts
{
  LedSign::Init();
  len = strlen (test);
}

void loop()                     // run over and over again
{
  // start empty
  LedSign::Clear(); 

  int potReading = analogRead (0);  // read A0
  int i = map (potReading, 0, 1023, 0, len * 6);  // starting pixel

  for (int j = 0; j < 14; j += 6) 
    Myfont::Draw(j, test[(i + j) / 6]); 

  delay(100);   // hold that image for a moment

}
```

Comment: I would expect to see a call to `analogRead()` if it supported using a pot though.

Comment: True, I left that change as an exercise for the reader. I thought the scrolling text part was the hard part, making the pot choose the position would be the easy part.

Comment: Could you please explain how to use the potentiometer to control the scrolling of a word. I have used examples and I have my word scrolling across the shield but have no idea how to control it with a potentiometer. Thank you

Comment: [Ignacio's answer](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/5195/10794) describes the idea. You take a reading, and use that to adjust where to start displaying the text from the middle of the string you want.

Comment: I have set two values for the potentiometer one below 127 and one above 127. So if I turn the pot one way I want the word to scroll to the right and if I turn the pot the other way the word scrolls in the other direction. I do not know how to write the code to apply this reading. Any code examples or points in the right direction would help.

Comment: Please stop posting questions as "answers" - this isn't a forum. If you want to ask your own question I suggest you start a new one. Include the code you are using in it.

Comment: See amended reply.